# Grid rowspacing does not seem to work in PancakeView

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following XAML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:yummy="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView"
             x:Class="BottomSlider.TestView">

    <yummy:PancakeView BackgroundColor="White"
                           Border="{yummy:BorderMarkup Color=Red, Thickness='1'} "
                           VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                           x:Name="MyDraggableView"
                           CornerRadius="60,60,0,0"
                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           HeightRequest="600" >

        <Grid>
            <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>

            <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="YellowGreen" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="Aqua" Grid.Row="2"/>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="Bisque" Grid.Row="3"/>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="BlanchedAlmond" Grid.Row="4"/>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="Blue" Grid.Row="5"/>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="DimGray" Grid.Row="6"/>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor= "HotPink" Grid.Row="7"/>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="Gold" Grid.Row="8"/>
        </Grid>
    </yummy:PancakeView>
</ContentPage>
```

It seems by setting `RowSpacing="0"` this does not seem to be working.
The image that follows is what the xaml looks like after running it on the emulator.

[image: Emulator screenshot]

Comment: with my knowledge whatever features you get in pancake are now available in Frame itself of xamarin forms version 4.8 so try once inside the frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining two nested `Grid`, but setting `RowSpacing="0"` only in the inner one which is empty and does not contains your `Boxview`. To answer your question keep only one `Grid`:

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="YellowGreen" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Aqua" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Bisque" Grid.Row="3"/>
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="BlanchedAlmond" Grid.Row="4"/>
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Blue" Grid.Row="5"/>
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="DimGray" Grid.Row="6"/>
    <BoxView BackgroundColor= "HotPink" Grid.Row="7"/>
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Gold" Grid.Row="8"/>
</Grid>
```

Or if for some reasons you want to keep both (at least in the code you shared, for me it doesn't make sens to have both), then you need to set it in the outter `Grid` 'the one that contains your `BoxView`:

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
....
```

Comment: can you be able explain to me remove the white spacing from the PancakeView for both the left and right margin as displayed in the image above. I have tried setting Margin="0,0,0,0" with no luck

Comment: @George I don't have the white space margins from sides in my emulator with exact code you shared. Sorry I can't reproduce. Are you changing anything in your code behind?